# Batch delete cookies in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

How can I delete all cookies for a domain in Google Chrome? I have this view:

[[image]<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6bCN.png)

But I can't select all cookies and click Delete, and there's no "Delete all cookies" button. I am forced to click each one, then press the Delete button, and the rows are small.

Am I missing an easier way?

Comment: have you tried ctrl+a then delete?

Comment: @0sh doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Go into Google Chrome Settings, open the Under the Hood Tab, go to Content Settings, go to All Cookies and Site Data, enter the domain in the search box, check in the overview that these are indeed all the cookies you want to remove, then hit delete all.

Comment: This. Just notice that the image in the original post is from the Web Inspector. The solution suggested here is under Chrome's settings, not the Web Inspector

Comment: Any way to do this without hosing the session data for every site?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "every site". You are only deleting cookies for the domain that you selected, not for every site. Use the search box to find the domain you're looking for. Then you can hit 'remove all' to remove the cookies that you've found. If you want more fine-grained you can also delete the cookies that appear on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CCleaner to do a blanket wipeout. I'm not sure how domain specific cookie removal works, but check out the settings.

You can get CCleaner for Mac [here](http://www.piriform.com/mac/ccleaner), as well as in the App Store (free). It works excellently.